# Mirror weight painting from left to right in a character

Tags: rigging, mirror

[image]

I've found that weight is not the same on both sides even if I already mirrored it.

Comment: Is your mesh using a mirror modifier? Do you have the names of the bones the same but with .L and .R? Did you use automatic weights to begin with?

Comment: yes, I did apply mirror modifier and flip the name from .l to .r
but the parent is not automatic weight, is empty vertex group

Comment: Yes, but if you applied the mirror modifier, then you have no mirror of the weight. The mirror modifier needs to be active for the mirrored weighting to work with the left and right bones.